# Vector - Find angle between two vector that form perpendicular vectors

Tags: vectors

Given that $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are two non-zero vector. The two vectors form 4 resultant vectors such that $\vec{a} + 3\vec{b}$ and $2\vec{a} - 3\vec{b}$ are perpendicular, $\vec{a} - 4\vec{b}$ and $\vec{a} + 2\vec{b}$ are perpendicular. How can I find the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$?

The answer given here is 114.09. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: well what do you know about vectors that would give you the angle between them?

Comment: Dot product: a * b = |a| |b| cos @

Comment: Alright! Leting $\vec c := \vec a+3\vec b$, $\vec d:= 2\vec a-3\vec b$, $\vec e := \vec a -4\vec b$, and $\vec f := \vec a +2\vec b$, we have $\vec c\cdot \vec d=0$ and $\vec e \cdot \vec f =0$. Now what is the formal definition of the dot product?

Comment: Incidentally, if you write an angle without units, then the units are radians (where $2\pi$ is a full circle). Presumably you mean $114.09^\circ$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given that $\left\langle a+3b,2a-3b\right\rangle=0$ and $\left\langle a-4b,a+2b \right\rangle=0$. Hence

$$\left\langle a+3b,2a-3b\right\rangle=2\left\langle a,a\right\rangle-9\left\langle b,b\right\rangle+3\left\langle a,b\right\rangle=0$$ and 
$$\left\langle a-4b,a+2b \right\rangle=\left\langle a,a \right\rangle-8\left\langle b,b \right\rangle-2\left\langle a,b \right\rangle=0.$$(Here I assumed that you are working with a real inner-product space).
By subtracting the second equation twice from the first, we obtain
$$\left\langle b,b \right\rangle+\left\langle a,b \right\rangle=0.$$

Plugging the previous equation into the second yields
$$\|a\|^2=6\|b\|^2.$$
Hence $\frac{\|b\|}{\|a\|}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{6}}.$

Now you know that $\left\langle a,b \right\rangle=\cos(\theta)\|a\|\|b\|.$
Thus, after plugging the previous results in the third equation, we get

$$\cos(\theta)=-\frac{\|b\|}{\|a\|}=-\sqrt{\frac{1}{6}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{cases}
(\vec{a}+3\vec{b}).(2\vec{a}-3\vec{b})=0,\\
(\vec{a}-4\vec{b}).(\vec{a}+2\vec{b})=0.
\end{cases}
$\Rightarrow$
\begin{cases}
2|\vec{a}|^2-9|\vec{b}|^2+3\vec{a}.\vec{b}=0,\\
|\vec{a}|^2-8|\vec{b}|^2-2\vec{a}.\vec{b}=0.
\end{cases}
$\Rightarrow$
\begin{cases}
|\vec{a}|^2=-6\vec{a}.\vec{b},\\
|\vec{b}|^2=-\vec{a}.\vec{b}.
\end{cases}
then
$$\cos\theta=\dfrac{\vec{a}.\vec{b}}{|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|}=\dfrac{\vec{a}.\vec{b}}{\sqrt{|\vec{a}|^2|\vec{b}|^2}}=\dfrac{\vec{a}.\vec{b}}{-\sqrt{6}\vec{a}.\vec{b}}=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$$
since $\vec{a}.\vec{b}=-|\vec{b}|^2<0$, so 
$$\theta=\pi-\arccos\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}=\pi-65^\circ.9=\color{blue}{114^\circ5'41''.4}$$

Comment: At $\cos \theta = 1/6$, how you know $\vec{a}. \vec{b} = 1$ ?

Comment: It sure looks like $\vec a\cdot\vec b$ is negative, so you've lost a sign.

Comment: $\vec{a}.\vec{b}=-|\vec{b}|^2<0$.

Comment: Currently there are two mistakes in the very last two equaltities before the blue answer.

Comment: Recall that $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$, not $x=\sqrt{x^2}$ and you forgot the squareroot in the last one. (Also this not critique, just simply pointing out the small errors at the end)

Comment: @Mathematician42 Thanks.